# how to extract a large SAS file?

Tags: sas

I have a large census data set with 20044425 observations and 35 variables. I am trying to get it to the work folder using the `mylib` statement. the specific variable I am interested in is a numeric variable titled `DISTRICT`. However, it is taking an extremely long time to extract it from my folder in the computer to the work folder in SAS

I tried to extract cases with the specific `DISTRICT` I am interested in using the following code

```
libname pop "\\Client\C$\Users\lakna\Desktop\SA data";
data mydata;
set pop.Sapop (where=(DISTRICT=3));
run;
```

However, it is still taking an extremely long time. It took more that 15 minutes of real time, and I was still not able to extract it to the work folder from the library.

Is there a more effecient way to extract a large file?

Comment: What is the libname statement for `pop`.  Please show the output from `options nocenter;
ods listing;
proc contents data=sashelp.class varnum;
run;
dm 'output';`  Some of the 34 other columns may be very wide character columns that can cause write times longer than expected.  The pop table may be on a network folder, or a SAS/Share libref; both require transport across your network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make this slightly faster, you can copy the data set over and then process it. When you use a COPY procedure it does not read all the data it moves it over in blocks so it should be very straightforward.

1. Copy the data over using PROC COPY
2. Filter the data set from WORK
3. Add a KEEP = to keep only the variables you need which will reduce the size fo the file.
4. If you're regularly working with this file consider adding an index on the commonly used variables to filter and/or using a COMPRESS option to reduce the size.

   ```
   libname pop "\\Client\C$\Users\lakna\Desktop\SA data";

   proc copy in=pop out=work;
   select SAPOP;
   run;

   data mydata;
   set sapop (where=(DISTRICT=3) KEEP = DISTRICT <list of variables>);
   run;
   ```

Comment: If you're only extracting a handful of short variables, and you have set the global option `compress = yes` it is sometimes optimal to set an explicit `compress = no` on the `data` statement. The overhead of the row-level compression that SAS uses can make narrow datasets balloon in size.

Comment: I would question whether the additional proc copy is particularly worthwhile here, unless the storage area used for the `work` library is significantly faster than the one for the `pop` library, and the dataset you're copying is subsequently being read multiple times.

Comment: @user667489 in general, things in WORK library process faster, mostly because it's local. COPY moves it over in blocks, so overall, in my experience, this does speed up the processing significantly. Will it work in all cases, no, but for what the OP said here, I think it will.

Answer (score 1):

Being on a file server, the contents of the data set is being transferred (by the libname engine) to your SAS session machine before the where clause can be applied.

Some different ways to get faster cuts is

- move the entire Sapop data set to your local machine
- get IT to install SAS on the file serving machine so that the share \Client\C$ is a local path
- Obtain a smaller cut from your census data provider